# React - This Suspense boundary received an update before it finished hydrating

Tags: reactjs

I seem to be getting these errors locally but it doesn't show on the production site:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: This Suspense boundary received an update before it finished hydrating. This caused the boundary to switch to client rendering. The usual way to fix this is to wrap the original update in startTransition.

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: This Suspense boundary received an update before it finished hydrating. This caused the boundary to switch to client rendering. The usual way to fix this is to wrap the original update in startTransition.

```
Call Stack
updateDehydratedSuspenseComponent
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (20702:0)
updateSuspenseComponent
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (20362:0)
beginWork
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (21624:0)
beginWork$1
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (27426:0)
performUnitOfWork
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26557:0)
workLoopSync
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26466:0)
renderRootSync
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26434:0)
performSyncWorkOnRoot
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26085:0)
flushSyncCallbacks
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (12042:0)
flushPassiveEffectsImpl
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (27060:0)
flushPassiveEffects
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26984:0)
eval
node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26769:0)
workLoop
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (266:0)
flushWork
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (239:0)
MessagePort.performWorkUntilDeadline
node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (533:0)
```

Any ideas how to resole this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to run a basic example first?

from NextJS docs here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

```js
// components/hello.js
export function Hello() {
  return <p>Hello!</p>
}

// pages/index.js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponent = dynamic(() =>
  import('../components/hello').then((mod) => mod.Hello)
)
```

Sometimes it helps to isolate the issue to the very fundamental.
Then you bring back all your additional code to localize the issue.

Somehow you seem to interrupt the hydration by providing new data, hard to say where without the source files. I won't start guessing here, try to pin down the code line(s) by smart isolating > putting back together.

How different is your prod/dev deployment? In my project both the same, but there are differences.. using `getInitialProps`? I think locally it will fetch everytime compared to prod, best start with understanding the differences from develop to prod...

if it's an **external library it might not fully support SSR, try to dynamically import using the `{ssr: false}` option** for this one?

That sounds reasonable to me. because:
1.) it's dynamically loaded (later ready) = inerruption of hydration
2.) server gets that new code and sees he cannot handle it, so he gives it back for client rendering

`import { useIsSSR } from "@react-aria/ssr";`

might be helpful to determine where you're code is running.

Comment: Not setting {ssr: false} for my dynamic import was the issue for me, many thanks!